# What's the fastest way to run a shell command in ruby?

Tags: ruby, shell, optimization

I've seen many times that the overhead of Kernel#` and `system(...)` themselves can be a bottleneck in scripts. There are sometimes ways of reducing the overall # of shell invocations, e.g. with `xargs`, but sometimes I do need to invoke the shell many times in a row. What's the fastest way to do this? (I don't need any special environment variable setup or anything like that, nor even always the result code or stdout)

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to know what you did to research this, what you tried to test/prove the question. Simple benchmarks will tell you the answer.

Comment: Sure, benchmarks if I had an encyclopedic knowledge of all the different ways to run shell commands in Ruby, all the different ways I could modify their invocations, maybe a deep dive into the C code behind it, etc.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the close. Do you see the 1 answer? I would not have thought that separating the arguments with commas would cause `system` to run any differently, even though I've already read the system documentation before. But hey, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember there's two ways to run an external process:

1. With `system("script with arguments")` where that *must* pass through the shell first.
2. With `system("script", "with", "arguments")` where the command is run directly, bypassing the shell. This can be slightly faster if spinning up a shell is expensive, which it can be depending on your shell's configuration.

Note that both of these involve a `fork`/`exec` cycle that cannot be avoided.

If you need to do a *lot* of processing you might want to look into how `xargs` can work for you, especially when you can feed in a list of files/arguments via [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html). If you can somehow separate the output, which could be simple or hard, you can get a lot of mileage out of one shell process.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like the two methods have pretty similar performance, but I guess it can't hurt to use the latter when perf is involved.

Comment: The second form, with discrete arguments, has several advantages, but the biggest is you won't have a risk of a shell exploit or bug. In the first case a user could send in a hostile "filename" that's just shell script, or just malformed filename like `untitled file.txt` which the shell will parse as two arguments. In the second form the arguments are fed *directly* to the target executable, they're not subject to interpretation.

Comment: A lot of apps are a file called `upload.xls; rm -rf /` away from disaster.